# update Opengl window continuously

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew

I'm using Qt and OpenGL and GLEW to map a texture on a quad and render it. I want to change the texture for each frame and update the window continuously. How can I force it to update continuously?

The problem is solved as mentioned in the comments by adding a timer and connecting it to a slot to signal update function.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the window continuously" ?

Comment: I want  to load the texture and display it and then load the second texture and display it and so on. now it updates the window every time the mouse moves. I am also using qt and OpenGL.

Comment: Then you should look at your main loop, if it waits for an event or if it polls for an event. I think qt waits for an event by default, hence blocking your loop. But i'm not sure.

Comment: How are you updating your window with your actual code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using qt to create the window and manage the events like when the mouse is moving, it may cause the application to wait for an event to happen before re-drawing the window. I think you could use a `QTimer` object and connect its timeout signal to your update function.

Otherwise, if you handle events with some `waitEvent()` function, change it with a non-blocking version.

Comment: Signal on `frameSwapped` may be better.

Comment: `frameSwapped` is a signal from `QQuickWindow` only, we don't event know if he is using it.

Comment: I'm using QGLWidget, adding just update at the end of paintGL also forces the rendering to continue, but is it a good solution?

Comment: From what I know, if you have a `QGLWidget`, it is the way to use it, but i never used qt with OpenGL

Answer (score 2):

If you mean swap the buffers you need to call your platform specific swap function (wglSwapBuffers, glXSwapBuffers etc.) every frame and make sure vsync is disabled. If you mean let the window resize it's not an open gl specific question, that's down to the windowing system, also.